# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 4) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 2, 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I got an error,ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 4) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 2, 4, 104)'.
I wrote codes,

```
# coding: utf-8
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn

from tflearn.layers.core import input_data,dropout,fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

tf.reset_default_graph()
net = input_data(shape=[2, 4, 104])
net = conv_2d(net, 4, 16, activation='relu')
net = max_pool_2d(net, 1)
net = tflearn.activations.relu(net)
net = dropout(net, 0.5)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 10, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.5, loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

trainDataSet = [[0.25,0.25,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0.25,0.25,1,1]]
trainLabel = [[0,1],[0,1],[1,0]]
model.fit(trainDataSet, trainLabel, n_epoch=100, batch_size=32, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True)
```

Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn.py", line 16, in <module>
    model.fit(trainDataSet, trainLabel, n_epoch=100, batch_size=32, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 216, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 339, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 818, in _train
    feed_batch)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/xxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1128, in _run
    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 4) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 2, 4, 104)'
```

I rewrote into

```
trainDataSet = np.array([[0.25,0.25,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0.25,0.25,1,1]])
trainLabel = np.array([[0,1],[0,1],[1,0]])
```

but same error happens.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: what is 104 in shape?

Comment: @Geeocode 104 is this 104 of `net = input_data(shape=[2, 4, 104])`

Comment: sure, but you have a trainDataSet shape(3,4)

Comment: You have to provide more information about what your expected output regarding trainlabel and what 104 stand for etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing from the [Tensorflow](http://tflearn.org/layers/conv/) documentation:

```
tflearn.layers.conv.conv_2d
```

> **Input:**
>
> **4-D Tensor** [batch, height, width, in_channels].

From other Tensorflow documentation:

```
tf.nn.conv2d
```

> Computes a 2-D convolution given **4-D input** and filter tensors.
>
> Given an input tensor of shape [batch, in_height, in_width,
>   in_channels] and a filter / kernel tensor of shape [filter_height,
>   filter_width, in_channels, out_channels], this op performs the
>   following:

Your dataset, label and input shape aren't aligning i.e. doesn't fit to each other.

Currently your `trainDataSet` has the shape of (3,4):

```
import numpy as np
trainDataSet = np.array([[0.25,0.25,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[0.25,0.25,1,1]])
print(trainDataSet.shape)
```

**Out:**

```
(3, 4)
```

But you defined the input shape as:

```
net = input_data(shape=[2, 4, 104])
```

Ambiguous what you really want to achieve, but if you wanted to see a simple working example, that your code should have been seen as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn

from tflearn.layers.core import input_data,dropout,fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

tf.reset_default_graph()
net = input_data(shape=[3, 4, 1])
net = conv_2d(net, 4, 16, activation='relu')
net = max_pool_2d(net, 1)
net = tflearn.activations.relu(net)
net = dropout(net, 0.5)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.5, loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

trainDataSet = [
    [
        [[0.25], [0.25], [1], [1]],
        [[0], [0], [1], [1]],
        [[0.25], [0.25], [1], [1]]
    ],
    [
        [[0.25], [0.25], [1], [1]],
        [[0], [0], [1], [1]],
        [[0.25], [0.25], [1], [1]]
    ],
    [
        [[0.25], [0.25], [1], [1]],
        [[0], [0], [1], [1]],
        [[0.25], [0.25], [1], [1]]
    ]
]

trainLabel = [[0,1],[0,1],[1,0]]
model.fit(trainDataSet, trainLabel, n_epoch=100, batch_size=32, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True)
```

**Out:**

```
---------------------------------
Run id: NHHJV7
Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Accuracy/ (raw) is illegal; using Accuracy/__raw_ instead.
---------------------------------
Training samples: 2
Validation samples: 1
--
Training Step: 1  | time: 1.160s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 0.0000 | val_loss: 23.02585 - val_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 2/2
--
Training Step: 2  | total loss: 0.62966 | time: 1.008s
| Adam | epoch: 002 | loss: 0.62966 - acc: 0.0000 | val_loss: 10.76885 - val_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 2/2
.
.
.
Training Step: 99  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.013s
| Adam | epoch: 099 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 1.0000 | val_loss: 23.02585 - val_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 2/2
--
Training Step: 100  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.011s
| Adam | epoch: 100 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 1.0000 | val_loss: 23.02585 - val_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 2/2
--
```